# jQuery accordion to serve as table of contents

Tags: javascript, beginner, jquery, html, css

I'm putting together a video website for our company, with a working accordion.  It works, but it using the same class name for each section creates issues with the expanding and collapsing.  I found a solution, but I'm going to need 13 similar sections for 13 lessons, and having to recreate the same code repeatedly in CSS, JS, and HTML, I have to believe there is a better way to do this.

As the "IT Guy" who just got tossed into this stuff, I'd like to create something a bit cleaner.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //lesson 1
  $('.l1-vid').click(function() {
    if($(this).next().is(':hidden') != true) {
    $(this).removeClass('active'); 
    $(this).next().slideUp("normal");
    } else {
    $('.l1-vid').removeClass('active');  
    $('#l1-vidlink').slideUp('normal');


    if($(this).next().is(':hidden') == true) {
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $(this).next().slideDown('normal');
     }   
  }
  });

  $('.l1').click(function() {
  if($(this).next().is(':hidden') != true) {
  $(this).removeClass('active'); 
  $(this).next().slideUp("normal");
  $('.l1-vid').removeClass('active');  
  $('#l1-vidlink').slideUp('normal');

  } else {
  $('.l1').removeClass('active');  
  $('.l1-info').slideUp('normal');

  if($(this).next().is(':hidden') == true) {
  $(this).addClass('active');
  $(this).next().slideDown('normal');
  }   
  }
  });

  //lesson 2
  $('.l2-vid').click(function() {
    if($(this).next().is(':hidden') != true) {
    $(this).removeClass('active'); 
    $(this).next().slideUp("normal");
    } else {
    $('.l2-vid').removeClass('active');  
    $('#l2-vidlink').slideUp('normal');


    if($(this).next().is(':hidden') == true) {
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $(this).next().slideDown('normal');
     }   
  }
  });

  $('.l2').click(function() {
  if($(this).next().is(':hidden') != true) {
  $(this).removeClass('active'); 
  $(this).next().slideUp("normal");
  $('.l2-vid').removeClass('active');  
  $('#l2-vidlink').slideUp('normal');

  } else {
  $('.l2').removeClass('active');  
  $('.l2-info').slideUp('normal');

  if($(this).next().is(':hidden') == true) {
  $(this).addClass('active');
  $(this).next().slideDown('normal');
  }   
  }
  });

  //Collapse all on load 
  $('.l1-info').hide();
  $('#l1-vidlink').hide();
  $('.l2-info').hide();
  $('#l2-vidlink').hide();

  //Expand all link
  $('.expand').click(function(event){
  $('.l2').next().slideDown('normal');
  {$('.l2').addClass('active');}
  $('.l1').next().slideDown('normal');
  {$('.l1').addClass('active');}
  }
  );

  //collapse all link
  $('.collapse').click(function(event){
  $('.l2').next().slideUp('normal');
  {$('.l2').removeClass('active');}
  $('.l2-vid').removeClass('active');  
  $('#l2-vidlink').slideUp('normal');
  $('.l1').next().slideUp('normal');
  {$('.l1').removeClass('active');}
  $('.l1-vid').removeClass('active');  
  $('#l1-vidlink').slideUp('normal');

  }
  );
  });
```

```css
@import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Volkhov:700,700italic,400italic,400);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald);
@font-face {
font-family : "'Oswald'";
font-style : normal;
font-weight : 400;
src : local('Oswald Regular'), local('Oswald-Regular'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/oswald/v8/Y_TKV6o8WovbUd3m_X9aAA.ttf) format('truetype');
}
body{
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: black;
    }
.content{
    width: 50%;
    margin: auto;
    }
ul{
  list-style: none;

  }
li{
  padding-left: inherit;
  list-style: circle;
  margin-left: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  padding-top: 3px;
  }

  /*---------------Lesson 1---------------*/
.l1 {  
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  background: #fff;
  padding-left:20px;
  padding-top:18px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #0079C1;
  display: block;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 1px;
  padding: 8px 15px;
  border: 1px solid #E5E5E5;   
  }
.l1::after{
    content: "+";
    float: left;
    padding-right: 15px;
    }

.l1-info {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    border: 1px solid #E5E5E5;
    padding-right: 31px;
    display: flex;
    }
.l1-vid{
    background: url('play.png') no-repeat left center !important;
    padding-left: inherit;
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: 0;
    }
.l1-vid a{
    cursor: pointer;
    }
.l1-vid::after{
    content: "" !important;
    }
#l1-vidlink{
    padding-left: inherit;  
    } 
  /*---------------End Lesson 1---------------*/

  /*---------------Lesson 2---------------*/
.l2 {  
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  background: #fff;
  padding-left:20px;
  padding-top:18px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #0079C1;
  display: block;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 1px;
  padding: 8px 15px;
  border: 1px solid #E5E5E5;   
  }
.l2::after{
    content: "+";
    float: left;
    padding-right: 15px;
    }

.l2-info {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    border: 1px solid #E5E5E5;
    padding-right: 31px;
    display: flex;
    }
.l2-vid{
    background: url('play.png') no-repeat left center !important;
    padding-left: inherit;
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: 0;
    }
.l2-vid a{
    cursor: pointer;
    }
.l2-vid::after{
    content: "" !important;
    }
#l2-vidlink{
    padding-left: inherit;  
    } 
  /*---------------End Lesson 2---------------*/  

.active::after{
    content: "-";
    float: left;
    padding-right: 15px;
    }
a:hover{
    text-decoration:underline   
    }
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {

  }
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <title>AAON Heating and Cooling Products</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="icon" href="p2tab.png">
   <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="accordionscript.js"></script> 


</head>
<body>
<div class="content">
<div>Prism2 - Operator Interface</div>

    <div style="float:right;font-size: small;"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="expand">Expand All</a> | <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="collapse">Collapse All</a></div><br>

    <div class="l1">Intro</div>
    <div class="l1-info">
    <ul>
    <li class="l1-vid"><a >Video</a></li>
    <div id="l1-vidlink">
                <iframe class="desktop"  width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/H7hGxg92Khc" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
    <li>Intro - PDF</li>
    <li>Prism 2 Technical Guide</li>
    </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="l2">What is Prism2?</div>
    <div class="l2-info">
    <ul>
    <li class="l2-vid"><a >Video</a></li>
    <div id="l2-vidlink">
                <iframe class="desktop"  width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/H7hGxg92Khc" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
    <li>What is Prism2 - PDF</li>
    </ul>
    </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

- Do not reinvent the wheel and pick up an existing component framework. For instance, [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) provides an [accordion component](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/collapse/#accordion-example) out of the box. You simply need to [drop in Bootstrap's CSS and JS](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/), then follow the prescribed markup, replacing the user-specific portions like the targets.
- You might also want to consider using [`<summary>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/summary) and [`<details>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details) elements to do accordions without having to bring in libraries or write down scripts. You can read HTML5Doctor's [analysis on `<summary>` and `<details>`](http://html5doctor.com/the-details-and-summary-elements/), its purpose and use cases.
- Your indents need to be consistent. This can be remedied by using a text editor that's geared towards code editing out of the box (instead of a plain text editor like Notepad). [Sublime Text](https://www.sublimetext.com/) or [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) should get you started. They allow you to set what your indent character and width are, and will indent a newline accordingly.
- Avoid inline styles, put all your CSS in a stylesheet, use classes. The only case that inline CSS is allowed is when you have dynamic values for styles (i.e. positioning with `top` and `left` based on some calculation not known ahead of time).
- Avoid using IDs. IDs are limiting in a sense that it can only be assigned to one element. If you have multiple elements that need styling, classes are a better fit. Also, IDs have high [specificity](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/), meaning it's harder to override unless you have a more specific selector - which can be a pain since a more specific selector means putting more into a selector making it unnecessarily long and brittle.
- Avoid styling element selectors directly and use classes. For instance, styling lists using `ul` and `li` as selectors assumes that ALL lists should look that way, but you don't really want that. Use classes and target specific elements. And while you're at it, use a naming convention, like [BEM](https://en.bem.info/methodology/key-concepts/).

Comment: Thank you! The Bootstrap made things MUCH easier!